# Example of product of open set is not open in the product topology?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Can some one give an example of as the title? I see some text saying that the open set in product topology is of the form $\prod_{s \in S} W_s$ such that $W_s$ open in $X_s$ and $W_s \ne X_s$ for only finitely many $s$. So, if I take product infinitely many $W_s$ open and $W_s \ne X_s$, is it an correct example?
Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it is. For example, if $X_s=\Bbb R$ for each $s\in S$, you can take $W_s=(0,1)$ for each $s\in S$. You should then prove that this product does not contain any non-empty open set in $\prod_{s\in S}X_s$.

Comment: Let $X_n=\{0,1\}$ with the discrete topology. Every one-point set $\{x\}$ in $X=\prod_{n\in\mathbb N}X_n$ is a product of open sets. If those one-point sets were open in $X$ then $X$ would be a discrete space. But $X$ is not discrete, seeing as it's an infinite compact space (homeomorphic to the Cantor set).